# How can I create a modified identity matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have an identity matrix in MATLAB which is used in some regression analysis for joint hypothesis tests. However, when I change the linear restrictions for my tests, I can no longer rely on the identity matrix.

To give a simple example, here is some code which produces an identity matrix depending on the value of `y`:

```
for i = [1, 2, 4]
  y = i
  x = 5;
  H = eye(y*x)
end
```

However, what I need is not the identity matrix, but the first two rows and all others to be zero.

For the first example, the code produces an `eye(5)`:

```
H =

     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     1
```

I need something that given `y` does not produce the identity but in fact produces:

```
H =

     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

Can I adjust the identity matrix to include zeroes only after the first two rows?

Comment: You haven't asked a question, merely stated what you need. Also you have shown no effort from your side in creating this matrix. Please read [ask], then [edit] your question accordingly, asking a question and presenting your own effort on the matter.

Comment: I totally agree, my effort on this is limited as I have totally no idea, the question is can I somehome adjust the identity matrix to include only zeros after the first two rows.

Comment: How's the factor of `2` suddenly there? Why is it `2`? The quickest way for the two would be `diag([ones(2,1); ones(5-2,1)])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425481/how-can-i-create-a-modified-identity-matrix/52426625?noredirect=1#comment91794394_52425481) you can use [`diag`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html):

```
diag([ones(2,1); zeros(x*y-2,1)])
```

This works because `diag` makes a vector become the main diagonal of a square matrix, so you can simply feed it the diagonal vector, which is your case would be 2 1s and the rest 0s.

Of course if you need a variable amount of 1s, which I was in doubt about hence the comment,

```
n=2;
diag([ones(n,1); zeros(x*y-n,1)])
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the simplest solution is to make a matrix of all zeroes and then just place the two ones by [linear indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#d120e1301):

```
H = zeros(x*y);
H([1 x*y+2]) = 1;
```

Generalizing the above to putting the first `N` ones along the diagonal:

```
H = zeros(x*y);
H(x*y.*(0:(N-1))+(1:N)) = 1;
```

Comment: `H=zeros(x,y);H(1:N,1:N)=eye(N)` does the same right?

Comment: @Adriaan: Yes, but that ends up setting more values than necessary (i.e. overwriting a bunch of zeroes with zero).

Comment: Not a big problem if `N=2`, but I see your point. Would `H(1:N,1:N)=speye(N)` be better?

Comment: @Adriaan: Probably not, since `H(1:N,1:N)` is still indexing into an `N`-by-`N` submatrix of `H`, and assigning it zeroes for the corresponding "empty" portions of the sparse matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some alternatives:

- Use [`blkdiag`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/blkdiag.html) to diagonally concatenate an identity matrix and a zero matrix:

  ```
  y = 5; x = 2;
  H = blkdiag(eye(x), zeros(y-x));
  ```
- A more exotic approach is to use element-wise comparisons with [singleton expansion](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and exploit the fact that [two `NaN`'s are not equal to each other](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html#f91-998324):

  ```
  y = 5; x = 2;
  H = [1:x NaN(1,y-x)];
  H = double(bsxfun(@eq, H, H.'))
  ```